# The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten, Error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, androidx

I am getting error and build failed, i am try to fix but not getting right solution;

my gradle file.

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'        
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 29
            buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "a3.girlogistic.com"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 29
                versionCode 41
                versionName "1.7.8"
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    shrinkResources false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'           
                }
                debug {
                   
        //            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        //            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
                }
            }
            buildFeatures  {
                //noinspection DataBindingWithoutKapt
                dataBinding = true
                viewBinding = true
            }
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
                targetCompatibility = '1.8'
            }
            aaptOptions {
                cruncherEnabled = false
            }
        }
        
        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01'
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
            //retrofit
            implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
            implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
            implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
            implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
            implementation 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
            //volley
            implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
            implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
            annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
            //circularimageview
            implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
        //    //crop image library...
            implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
        
            implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
            implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
            //gson
            implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
            implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
            implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-rc02'
        
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
            implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4'
            //butterknife
            implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
            annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
            implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.4.0"
            //calendar
            implementation 'com.github.tizisdeepan:eventscalendar:1.6.1'
            implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1"
            implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0-alpha06"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
            //Room database
            implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.2.5'
            annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.2.5'
            testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5"
            implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.1'
            implementation 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.3.4'
            implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01'
        
            implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.3.1'
        
            // reactive
            implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9"
            implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
            implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1@aar') {
                transitive = true
            }
            //noinspection GradleCompatible
            implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
            implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
```

changed application Id for security reasons.

Comment: First step remove `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3`

Comment: @Gabriele Thanks bro you save my day